# Passing file from one if to other if to finish proccses

Tags: php

**I already opened Question relative to this**(i flaged the question for moderator review),but no one finish help me.. and i stuck .

I have somthing like that :

```
if ($proc == "question")
{
    // Handle some normal form 'contact us'.

    // ... Some proccses code when submited via ajax ...

    $fileElementName = 'ImageBrowse';

    if (isset($_FILES[$fileElementName]) && !empty($_FILES[$fileElementName]))
    {
        // I want that file come to here from 'sendQueuploadimg'.
        $file = $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name']; 
    var_dump($file);
    }
}
else if ($proc == "sendQuestionUploadImg")
{
    // Handle img upload via ajax.

    $fileElementName = 'ImageBrowse';

    $uploadsDirectory = '../uploads/'; 

    $allowedTypes = array
        (
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/png',
            'application/x-rar-compressed'
        );

    // ... Some more proccses code when submited via ajax ...

    // In the end if goes well...
    // I want to pass the file array to the other if above.

    if (isset($msg) && !empty($msg))
    {
        $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name'];
        // How to pass the file to above if 'question'?
    }
    else
    {
        @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]); 
    }
}
```

I'v tried to make a class and tranfer the file to function inside class, it's worked, but when I tried to pull out the file from the function I got `null`, I've tried like more 10 other way to transfer the file to there but no succses.

```
<?php
    class image
    {
        public $file;
        public function setImgTmp($file)
        {
            // When I do var_dump I will see the file here
            // But I can't pull it out.
            $this->file = $file;
            return $this->file;
        }
    };
    $file = new image();
?>
```

Above is one of the couple attempts that I tried to pass the file, but it wont work, I can't call the function without the `$file` paramater.

Anybody got an idea how to pass the tmp file to the other if above if submited?

Comment: can you please explain better your needings? you need a class to handle a file ?

Comment: No,i need to transfer the file from one if to the other if..like in example.

Comment: u can't "transfer" into an if...

Comment: Why not  ?  the tmp file keep on the server till the script terminated, and i already could pass the tmp file inside class ..and i ment passing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it: the two "ifs" reflect two states in a user session. A bit complicated english though, it's not the if but the state variable `$proc` which gives the clue and the issue is to pass (!) the results from one state to the other.

Thats usually done in the $_SESSION variable:

```
....
if($proc == "question"){// Handle some normal form 'contact us'.

    $fileElementName = $_SESSION['imgfilename']; // make some error handing on null !!

....
```

and

```
 ....
 if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){

      $_SESSION['imgfilename'] = $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name']; 
 ....
```

etc.

Annotation: you need to start a session first to use the $_SESSION variable, see the docs!

Comment: Well this really worked , and i think about that before , but didn't try ... unsecure way but its working and i dont care lol, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's only insecure as long as you go with PHPs standard session storage (file based). There are more safe mechanisms, but in general, there's nothing insecure about sessions itself.